# How do I compare the s[] to char vowels?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{

    string s;
    //char a[5][8];
    getline(cin,s);
    int m= s.length();
    char a[m][8];
    //a == &city[0];
    //s
    char vowels[]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
    for (int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] !=*vowels)//, 'e' , 'i' , 'o' , 'u'))
        {
         s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
        }
        else //if (s[i]=vowels[5])
        {
         s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
        }
       cout << s[i] ;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I am trying make all the vowels in uppercase and all consonents lowecase, but code is not working whats wrong with this?

Comment: `s[i] !=*vowels` only checks if `s[i]` is equal to `'a'`, for a start.

Comment: Is there a reason you can use `std::string` and string methods?

Comment: what is that Alan? I appreciate your help polynomial. What exactly should i do?